# Trying to Update Multiple Fields in Database at once

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a PHP that collects the data successfully from the original form on another page. I know this because I have ran my own debugging technique and it shows that all the variables are coming through successfully.

My Problem is in the script below. I'm trying to make it update more than one field in table, but when the `$firstop` and `$secondop` with their values come through, it only updates the `$firstop` choice. How can this be fixed?

```
<?php 
 $fname         = trim($_POST['upname']); 
 $sname         = trim($_POST['upsurename']);
 $firstop       = trim($_POST['firstup']);
 $update1       = trim($_POST['update1']);
 $secondop      = trim($_POST['secondup']);
 $update2    = trim($_POST['update2']);
 $var = trim($_POST['submit']);
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fypannadale");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
 if (isset($firstop)) {
   switch ($firstop) {
     case "FirstName":
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET FirstName='$update1'
         WHERE FirstName='$fname' AND LastName='$sname'");
         break;
     case "LastName":
       mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET  LastName='$update1'
         WHERE FirstName='$fname' AND LastName='$sname'");
         break;
   }
 }
 if (isset($secondop)) {
   switch ($secondop) {
     case "FirstName1":
       mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET FirstName='$update2' WHERE FirstName='$fname' AND LastName='$sname'");
       break;
     case "LastName1":
       mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET LastName='$update2' WHERE FirstName='$fname' AND LastName='$sname'");
       break;
   }
 }?>
```

Comment: `$secondop = trim($_POST['secondup']);` Perhaps your post item is named 'secondop' not 'secondup'. You should be validating and sanitizing  these values though. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: add `echo  $secondop;die();` after ` $secondop      = trim($_POST['secondup']);` to check that. if page doesn't display anything, you haven't get a value for $secondop

Comment: Im not quite sure how parameterized queries work, its the first I have heard of them. I have been validating the queries and they are all submitted to the page successfully. I ran the check Janaka, it gives the value that its meant to. It just wont update 2 different fields at once, why would that be?